# Why is "docker-compose up" command giving me an error?(Closed)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've just cloned a project and when I run command `docker-compose up` it's giving me

```
Step 2/20 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssl     git     unzip     zlib1g-dev     libzip-dev     libgpgme11-dev     libpng-dev     -y 
gnupg     && pecl install gnupg     && docker-php-ext-enable gnupg     && docker-php-ext-install gd
1 error occurred:
        * Status: Invalid signal: SIGQUIT, Code: 1
```

I'm using latest version of docker, my OS is Windows 10 Pro 64. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: you got a second `-y` flag in the middle of packages. If that does not caused the error: Try to run with verbose flag `docker compose --verbose up` or build without compose to get full logs.

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find the command online, what is the build without compose command?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/ You have to give the options from compose-file then by arguments.. This is just an escalation if compose with the verbose flag does not show helping output.. Or edit `dockerfile` of this and pull the steps apart (by creating several `RUN` commands instead of chaining all by `&&`). Then you'll see the specific command which breaks the build process.

Comment: You're welcome. I wrapped all up in one answer for others. will delete comments after that. Feel free to mark as solved by this answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping up comments:

- Typo: Second `-y` flag in the `apt-get install` command.

Steps to debug:

- use verbose flag to get extended logs: `docker compose --verbose up`
- Edit `dockerfile` and  pull the steps apart (by creating several RUN commands instead of chaining all by &&). Then you'll see the specific command which breaks the build process.
- Use `docker build` instead of compose to build this specific image without all the compose overhead (especially in big projects with several services). To change compose args to docker cli args see [Reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build)